# Blank all WooCommerce shipping checkout fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field, checkout

I came across with this [How to blank all WooCommerce checkout fields by default except country?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55307899/how-to-blank-all-woocommerce-checkout-fields-by-default-except-country/55308999#55308999) similar question which has an answer code that meet my needs, but this code will blank all woocommerce shipping and also billing checkout field when customer click checkout button.

if I want the shipping fields only to be blank, how the code will looks like?

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks sir for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To blank all WooCommerce shipping checkout fields, you will use the following:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_get_value', 'checkout_get_value_filter', 10, 2 );
function checkout_get_value_filter( $value, $input ) {
    if ( strpos($input, "shipping_") === 0 ) {
        return '';
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Or also this specifying each related shipping field key:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_get_value', 'checkout_get_value_filter', 10, 2 );
function checkout_get_value_filter( $value, $input ) {
    $key_fields = array(
        'shipping_first_name',
        'shipping_last_name',
        'shipping_company',
        'shipping_country',
        'shipping_address_1',
        'shipping_address_2',
        'shipping_city',
        'shipping_country',
        'shipping_state',
        'shipping_postcode',
    );
    
    if ( in_array($input, $key_fields) ) {
        return '';
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Code goes on functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.